# DrawRect not called due to active main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I have an architecture that takes input from the mic and then performs some calculations and then should render to screen.

The issue is that calling `setNeedsDisplay` never triggers a call to drawRect because the main thread is running the calculations.

What would be the best way to thread this?

Create a single serial queue and dispatch the work to this background queue using GCD and dispatch the final setNeedsDisplay back to the main queue, or is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

keep everything long running off the main thread. that is best in my opinion. Long running calculations are also something

try to never block the UIThread

Comment: Yes, I have it working now, I just thought that there was a more efficient way to push the work to another thread as I am doing it inside an audio render callback. Without the threading headache, GCD doesnt seem to impact the performance.

Answer (score 0):

> ...work to this background queue using GCD and dispatch the final
>   setNeedsDisplay back to the main queue, or is there a more efficient
>   way of doing this?

Based on your pretty vague description, I'd say what you suggested is the best approach.

And if you do this with GCD, your code will be easy to read since the blocks of work you perform are inline in your code making it easy to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

> Create a single serial queue and dispatch the work to this background queue using GCD and dispatch the final setNeedsDisplay back to the main queue, or is there a more efficient way of doing this?

You should use the highest level API available to you.  In this case, it's NSOperation or one of its subclasses.  Probably, [NSBlockOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSBlockOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) is the one you want.  You should

- [create a block operation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSBlockOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008157-CH1-SW4) with the block you want executing
- [Set its completion handler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004591-RH2-SW36) to invoke setNeedsDisplay
- Stick it on an [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSOperationQueue).

The completion handler needs to invoke setNeedsDisplay on the main thread.  You can do this by sending [performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-CJBEHAEF) to the view e.g.

```
[myViewThatNeedsUpdating performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(setNeedsDisplay) 
                                          withObject: nil 
                                       waitUntilDone: NO];
```

I think this is a better approach than using GCD directly because it is more in the Objective-C idiom, it separates the work you are doing from the notification at the end and gives you many more options for how things get done than raw GCD.  For instance, if you want several of these things to happen sequentially, you can make some operations dependencies of others without having to write lots of code.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I ended up using a dispatch_async to a serial queue that does the heavy work and then at the end of the call chain I just dispatch back to the main thread and call setNeedsDisplay. Which seems to work alright for now with minimum code. I am not a fan of the added work needed to setup an NSOperation subclass if it is not entirely beneficial over GCD. It is probably slower too as it is built on GCD, which in this case I need rendering to happen immediately. (although the execution time frame when dispatching async back to main thread is uncertain.